# How to find the highest and the lowest number C#

Tags: c#

I get three values from three variables. How can i check who is the highest number and who is the lowest number?

The numbers are represented like this:

```
private int _score1; 
private int _score2; 
private int _score2;
```

Code:

```
Public int Highest
{
  return the highest number here;
}

public int Lowest
{
  return the lowest number here;
}
```

Can i calculate the highest and the lowest number in my constructor?

Comment: You pass the 3 numbers to your constructor?

Comment: 2 int with same name ? _score2? Public? Functions without () ? your constructor?

Comment: So where is the problem?

Comment: If this is homework, please tag appropriately.

Comment: Also, `Highest` and `Lowest` are properties? I see no constructor there...

Comment: @HPT Its not possible he has _score2 twice in his constuctor because it wouldn't compile. This almost sounds like a homework question. I will give him a few minutes to update his question he can tag his question and provide more details. @Bruno - He didn't past the entire class, Highest and Lowest are pseudo-code.

Comment: I'm sure he meant _score3 for the third one

Comment: @Ramhound: Since the scores are private and he asks about calculating then in the constructor, I'd like to know what he is passing the constructor. That's why I asked, maybe he's mixing up Constructors and Properties.

Answer (score 9):

The obligatory Linq answer:

```
Public int Highest(params int[] inputs)
{
  return inputs.Max();
}

public int Lowest(params int[] inputs)
{
  return inputs.Min();
}
```

The beauty of this one is that it can take any number of integer inputs. To make it fail-safe you should check for a null/empty inputs array (meaning nothing was passed into the method).

To do this without Linq, you basically just have to mimic the logic performed by the extension method:

```
Public int Lowest(params int[] inputs)
{
   int lowest = inputs[0];
   foreach(var input in inputs)
      if(input < lowest) lowest = input;
   return lowest;
}
```

Again, to make it foolproof you should check for an empty or null inputs array, because calling Lowest() will throw an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @Tomten - You can just put the values into an array and use a quick sort ( look it up ) then assigned the variables accordingly.  I feel strange about actually giving you the full answer.

Comment: Again, the most easily read way to do it, it's a good simple and extendable solution, nice.

Comment: @Ramhound; sorting the list is a bit excessive; you just have to scan the list for the lowest element.

Comment: He want another way to do it, didn't provide a reason, so I provided a method I knew he could use if this is indeed homework.

Answer (score 7):

This is one way to do it:

```
public int Highest
{
    get { return Math.Max(_score1, Math.Max(_score2, _score3)); }
}

public int Lowest
{
    get { return Math.Min(_score1, Math.Min(_score2, _score3)); }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
int[] numbers = new[] { _score1, _score2, _score3 };
int min = numbers.Min();
int max = numbers.Max();
```

Comment: It appears Min and Max are not available in .NET Framework 2.0. In which version were these functions introduced?

Comment: They aren't available in any version; not as members of int[] anyhow.  Min and Max are statics on the Math class.  Since at least version 1.1 of the framework.

Comment: Actually Min and Max are part of Linq introduced in 3.0.

Comment: Huh. Looks like I've learned my something new for the day. And it's not even noon yet.  (Evidently the file where I tried that syntax didn't have a using for Linq.)

Answer (score 3):

Highest
`return (x > y) ? (x > z ? x : z) : (y > z ? y : z)`

Lowest
`return (x < y) ? (x < z ? x : z) : (y < z ? y : z)`

Comment: Eh, seems unnecessarily tricky and hard to fix errors.  Hand-simulate this!

Answer (score 2):

Here's something you could do:

```
public class Numbers
{
    private int _number1;
    private int _number2;
    private int _number3;

    public readonly int Highest;
    public readonly int Lowest;

    public Numbers(int num1, int num2, int num3)
    {
        int high;
        int low;

        _number1 = num1;
        _number2 = num2;
        _number3 = num3;

        high = num1 > num2 ? num1 : num2;
        high = high > num3 ? high : num3;

        low = num1 < num2 ? num1 : num2;
        low = low < num3 ? low : num3;

        Highest = high;
        Lowest = low;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply check which is the highest you can do this

```
private int _highest = _score1;  
if (_score2 > _highest)  
  _highest = _score2  
if (_score3 > _highest)  
  _highest = _score3
```

Similarly, you can find the lowest like so

```
private int _lowest = _score1;  
if (_score2 < _lowest)  
  _lowest = _score2  
if (_score3 < _lowest)  
  _lowest = _score3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ-to-Objects, you could do something like this.

```
var numbers = new [] {_score1, _score2, _score3};
numbers.Sort();
var lowest = numbers.First();
var highest = numbers.Last();
```

Comment: using Linq to Objects, you'd prefer Max() and Min()

Comment: I like this, it's tried, tested and easily extended. Its also going to be the most straightforward to read and understand in my opinion.

Comment: @Jimmy - I forgot about Min/Max. Yes, those would be better.

Answer (score 0):

For a reference: in some cases you'll be having more than three variables (possibly not knowing how many). If they are stored in an array, here's the way to do it:

```
int Highest(int[] numbers)
{
    int highest = Int32.MinValue();

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] > highest)
            highest = numbers[i];
    }

    return highest;
}

int Lowest(int[] numbers)
{
    int lowest = Int32.MaxValue();

    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < lowest)
            lowest = numbers[i];
    }

    return lowest;
}
```

This will work for any length of int array.

Answer (score 0):

**Find the Largest and smallest number**

```
using System;

namespace LargeSmall;

{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {

            float large, small;
            int[] a = new int[50];
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the size of Array");
            int max = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the array elements");
            for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
            {
                string s1 = Console.ReadLine();
                a[i] = Int32.Parse(s1);
            }
            Console.Write("");
            large = a[0];
            small = a[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < max; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] > large)
                    large = a[i];
                else if (a[i] < small)
                    small = a[i];
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Largest element in the array is {0}", large);
            Console.WriteLine("Smallest element in the array is {0}", small);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple logic for finding Smallest Number

Input : 11, 0 , 3, 33 Output : "0"

```
namespace PurushLogics
{
    class Purush_SmallestNumber
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int count = 0;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Total Number of Integers\n");
            count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            int[] numbers = new int[count];

            Console.WriteLine("Enter the numbers"); // Input 44, 55, 111, 2 Output = "2"
            for (int temp = 0; temp < count; temp++)
            {
                numbers[temp] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            int smallest = numbers[0];
            for (int small = 1; small < numbers.Length; small++)
            {
                if (smallest > numbers[small])
                {
                    smallest = numbers[small];
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Smallest Number is : \"{0}\"",smallest);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```