# Finding min and max of user input data C# (without Linq)

Tags: c#

I have a program that I am working on to practice for a midterm, it is a simple Gradebook program that allows the user to input as many grades from 0-100 as they want. I have various things that calculate at the end that work fine but I need the program to also display the lowest and the highest grades. I saw another post where someone talks about linq (?) I have not worked with this and haven't researched it yet. I figure if it isn't in the book I shouldn't need it yet. the code is long so I will try to only include what I think is necessary...

```
    using System;

    public class GradeBook
{
private int total;
private int gradeCounter;
private int aCount;
private int bCount;
private int cCount;
private int dCount;
private int fCount;

// automatic popert CourseName
public string CourseName { get; set; }
```

then in order to get the user input

```
 public void InputGrades()
{
    int grade; //grade made by user
    string input; //text entered by user

    Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}",
        "enter integer in the range of 0-100.",
        "Type <ctrl> Z and press endter to terminate input:");

    input = Console.ReadLine(); //user input

    //loop until user enters the end of file indicator
    while (input != null)
    {
        grade = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        total += grade; //create total to form sum
        ++gradeCounter;//increment the number of grades for average

        // call method to increment appropriate counter
        IncrementLetterGradeCounter(grade);

        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }//end while(input != null)
```

This is my first post to SO so if there is something I have done wrong please let me know. If more code is necessary let me know.

Comment: What is your **question**?

Comment: If you want to find the *lowest* grade and the *highest* grade, you need to compare each value with the current lowest and current highest. If it is lower than the lowest, replace (same with highest).

Comment: Well, at least this one has some code.  OK, we don't know if it works or not, or what the problems/s are, but still...

Comment: Yeah - initialize lowest with 100 and highest with 0.

Comment: This question has an answer that demonstrates crashmstr's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390763/how-to-find-the-highest-and-the-lowest-number-c-sharp

Comment: there are no problems with it as it stands. the program runs but I am looking to be led down the right path. Ill Check crashmstr's against the link that jac gave.

Answer (score 2):

Add these two under int grade

```
int high = 0; 
int low = 100;
```

And then in your while loop

```
if(input > high) high = input;
if(input < low) low = input;
```

And then after your while loop.

```
Console.WriteLine("The highest grade was: " + high);
Console.WriteLine("The lowest grade was: " + low);
```

Comment: so this is essentially making a variable out of high and low and then doing what crashmstr suggested and essentially doing a bubble sort? Am I getting this somewhat right?

Comment: I'm not sure i would call it a bubble sort. But yes, you will get the highest and lowest grade and then you can store it where ever you need
(Please accept my answer if it solved your question :-))

Comment: There is no sort at all here. The order of the array, list, whatever remains unchanged. You are only finding the high and low values.

Comment: so officially it is not a sort but the gist of it is that it is checking every new piece of data until the loop terminates. If it is higher/lower it stores it in the new variable declared Max/Min... Okay this is making sense now. Sorry for seeming dense but ive only been programming for a few weeks so I havent quite conditioned my brain to think like a programmer yet. Im getting there!